# Python setup won't install numpy, but pip will

Tags: python, numpy, pip, setuptools

My package has the following setup file:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

requirements = [
    "numpy >= 1.6.1",
    "pyvisa >= 1.8",
    "pydaqmx >= 1.3.2",
    "pytest >= 3.0.2",
    "flask >= 0.11.1",
    "flask-socketio >= 2.7.1"
]

setup(name='hw_test_runner',
      version='0.26',
      description='My description',
      author='Jason R. Jones',
      author_email='my_email@email.com',
      url='https://myurl.com/...',
      packages=find_packages(),
      include_package_data=True,
      install_requires=requirements,
      zip_safe=False)
```

When I attempt installation, I get a numpy installation error:

```
error: Setup script exited with error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

But I can then `pip install numpy` into that environment, then re-rerun the setup for my project and all works quite well.

I would prefer that my setup script would properly install numpy on its own.  Any thoughts?

j

Comment: Need determine which `C++` used for compiling source code. Pip used `os level` compiler, did you have any idea what is your default compiler. Check `pip configuration` files, will be guide you !